# Need to automate sorting while accounting for overlapping values in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm facing a challenging request that's had me beating my head against the keyboard. I need to implement a script which will sort and summarize a dataset while accounting for overlapping values which are associated with different identifiers. The table from which I am selecting contains the following columns:

- BoxNumber (Need to group by this value, which serves as the identifier)
- ProdBeg (Contains the first 'page number' for the document/record)
- ProdEnd (Contains the last 'page number' for the document/record)
- DateProduced (Date the document was produced)
- ArtifactID (Unique identifier for each document)
- NumPages (Contains the number of pages associated with each document)

Selecting a sample of the data with no conditions resembles the following (sorry for lousy formatting):

```
BoxNumber | ProdBeg | ProdEnd | DateProduced | ArtifactID | NumPages

1200 | ABC01 | ABC10 | 12/4/2013 | 1564589 | 10

1201 | ABC11 | ABC20 | 12/4/2013 | 1498658 | 10

1200 | ABC21 | ABC30 | 12/4/2013 | 1648596 | 10

1200 | ABC31 | ABC40 | 12/4/2013 | 1489535 | 10
```

Using something like the following effectively groups and sorts the data by box number while accounting for different DateProduced dates, but does not account for overlapping ProdBeg/ProdEnd values between different BoxNumbers:

```
SELECT BoxNumber, MIN(ProdBeg) AS 'ProdBeg', MAX(ProdEnd) AS 'ProdEnd', DateProduced, COUNT(ArtifactID) AS 'Documents', SUM(NumPages) AS 'Pages'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY BoxNumber, DateProduced
ORDER BY ProdBeg, ProdEnd
```

This yields:

```
BoxNumber | ProdBeg | ProdEnd| DateProduced | Documents| Pages
1200 | ABC01 | ABC40 | 12/4/2013 | 3 | 30
1201 | ABC11 | ABC20 | 12/4/2013 | 1 | 10
```

Here, it becomes apparent that the ProdBeg/ProdEnd values for box 1201 overlap those for box 1200. No variation on the script above will work, as it will inherently ignore any overlaps and only select the min/max. We need something which will produce the following result:

```
BoxNumber | ProdBeg | ProdEnd | DateProduced | Documents| Pages
1200 | ABC01 | ABC10 | 12/4/2013 | 1 | 10
1201 | ABC11 | ABC20 | 12/4/2013 | 1 | 10
1200 | ABC21 | ABC40 | 12/4/2013 | 2 | 20
```

I'm just not sure how we can group by box number without showing only distinct values (which can result in overlaps for ProdBeg/ProdEnd). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! The environment version is SQL 2008 R2 (SP1).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for looking--this is on SQL 2008 R2 (SP1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuch.  This would be helped at least if you had `lead()`/`lag()` as in SQL Server 2012.  But it is doable.

The idea is the following:

1. Add a variable that is the *number* part of the code (the last two digits).
2. Calculate the next number in the sequence.
3. Calculate a flag if there is a gap to the next number.  This is the start of a "group".
4. Calculate the cumulative sum of the "start of a group" flag.  This is a group id.
5. Do the aggregation.

The following query follows this logic.  I didn't include the date produced.  This seems redundant with the number, unless a box can appear on multiple days.  (Adding the date produced is just a matter of adding the condition to the `where` clauses.)  The resulting query is:

```
with bp as (
      select t.*,
             cast(right(prodbeg, 2) as int) as pbeg,
             cast(right(prodend, 2) as int) as pend
      from mytable t
     ),
     bp1 as (
      select bp.*,
             (select top 1 pbeg
              from bp bp2
              where bp2.pbeg < bp.pbeg and pb2.BoxNumber = pb.BoxNumber
              order by bp2.pbeg desc
             ) as prevpend
      from bp
     ),
     bp2 as (
      select bp1.*,
             (select sum(case when prevpend = pbeg - 1 then 0 else 1 end)
              from bp1 bp1a
              where bp1a.pbeg < bp1.pbeg and pb1a.BoxNumber = pb1.BoxNumber
             ) as groupid
      from bp1
     )
select BoxNumber, MIN(ProdBeg) AS ProdBeg, MAX(ProdEnd) AS ProdEnd, DateProduced,
       COUNT(ArtifactID) AS 'Documents', SUM(NumPages) AS 'Pages'
FROM bp2
GROUP BY BoxNumber, groupid
ORDER BY ProdBeg, ProdEnd;
```

Comment: Wow, mind=BLOWN! I plugged this in and it's got me VERY close. It seems to be separating the first record from each 'group', then placing the rest of the group in the next row. So, every other row is 1 document, with the rest of the 'groupable' documents for that group in the next row. I'll be studying this for some time, but I'm going to try playing with it to see if I can't get it to combine the first row for each group with the second. I'm amazed to have gotten a response like this, and so quickly. You are a true master of your craft, sir.

Comment: This is my first foray into stackoverflow--to my dispmay, it appears I'm unable to give you a positive vote... :-/

Comment: @user3113047 . . . Yes, the logic was off.  It was identifying the last record before a gap rather than the first one afterwards.  I think I just fixed that.

Comment: . . This is fantastic! Thank you so much. I still need to play a bit; grouping is still off (I think it has something to do with the fact that ProdBeg and ProdEnd can extend as far as 5 places from the right e.g. ABCD00012345, but plugging in '5' instead of '2' for pbeg and pend is not sufficient). This is probably just related to the data in my environment--I'd bet the logic here is sound.